# Wait for async method to execute before iterating forEach loop: Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm calling a method that is executing some async operations and I want to wait for those methods to be completed before iterating the loop, so that the async operations are done sequentially. But I'm having trouble understanding how this can be achieved. Here is what I'm doing:

```
_.forEach(this.pendingUsers.queue, (user) => {
  this.myService.setUserInfo(user);
});
```

In the above I would like to add a logic that doesn't increment for loop until setUserInfo() is completed.

NOTE: I'm using Lodash 4's forEach method, so please ignore a different syntax.

Comment: Does `setUserInfo(user)` return an Observable? If yes, then you might wanna `merge` all the `setUserInfo` into one Observable then subscribe to that ONE Observable after the forEach loop. Again, this might be out of context also.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to achieve the result (im not using separate http service in order to keep all code in one place)

**With to promise** is the first solution, in which im using the async await function from es5. Im creating loop and in that loop im awaiting results from the call made in the loop, and only after that the next request is called.

**With observables** the second solution is more angularDev friendly and is using the `rxjs` `Subject` which is such object that emits event upon calling the `.next()` method over the instance of the `Subject`. Here is important to notice that we must unsubscribe at some point from the subject, or we will fall in an infinite loop, which is not cool, also notice that im using the `first()` operator in order to avoid unhanded subscriptions

Here is a live demo [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w07kvp53ol) *look at the console

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { first } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  dumySubject = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let currentIndex = 1;

    //With toPromise
    let indexes = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let someFunc = async () => {
      for (const id of indexes) {
        let someResp = this.http
          .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + id)
          .toPromise()
          .then(x => {
            console.log(x);
          });
        await someResp;
        console.log("___");
      }
    };
    someFunc();

    //With observables
    let sub = this.dumySubject.subscribe(x => {
      console.log("in");
      if (currentIndex > 5) {
        sub.unsubscribe();
      }
      this.http
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + currentIndex)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(x => {
          console.log(x);
          console.log("________");
          currentIndex++;
          this.dumySubject.next();
        });
    });
    this.dumySubject.next();

    console.log("i m the first line");
  }
}
```